# Erro em script de grant all

Tags: linux, script

Estou com um probleminha em um script que teoricamente dará permissão a um grupo especifico em um banco postgresql.

Segue script:

```
#!/bin/bash
su postgres -l -c "psql -c 'grant all on database teste_semanal to grp.teste_own;'"
```

O que acontece, quando rodo o script dá erro no ponto, um erro de sintaxe:

> ERRO: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "."
>   LINHA 1: grant all on database teste_semanal to group grp.teste...

Se eu trocar o usuário ou grupo por um nome sem ponto, exemplo teste funciona normal.
Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe como faço para esse usuário com ponto ser reconhecido.

Comment: Não faltou as aspas dupla interna? `...to "grp.teste_own";'"`

Comment: Não com aspas também dá o mesmo erro. Ele simplesmente não está reconhecendo o ponto.

Comment: Tenta colocar um scape grant all on `database teste_semanal to grp\.teste_own`

Comment: Uma coisa similar foi resolvida aquí do mesmo jeito que falou o @Ismael http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293595/postgresql-escaping-dash-in-username